# <something> and <something> is enough or are enough?

Tags: single-word-requests

> You don't have to call me again to confirm about our meeting - just
>   this one e-mail from you and my reply to it ***is*** well enough.

Should it be "is" or "are" in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the simple rules for numbering still apply here, so "*x* and *y* **are** enough" is correct.

"Will suffice" would also work in a more formal situation.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely "is". The reason is because there is a singular subject, not a plural subject. What's the subject? The subject is *reply*. You must remember, the sentence really is :

> My reply....is...

That should make it clearer. Thus, if your subject is singular, your verb needs to be singular as well. "is" is the singular form, while 'was" is the plural form. So use "is".

Comment: Seems to me that the subject is the email *and* the reply, not just the reply.

Comment: @Thursagen - Did you want to say "are" instead of "was"?

Comment: @Thursagen - If your answer is correct then I need to rephrase my sentence, because my original meaning in it was that the **combination** (of one e-mail and a reply to it) would suffice. That means that only the e-mail is not enough, and only the reply is not enough either.

Comment: @brilliant, I misunderstood your original meaning. In order to make it absolutely clear, perhaps you could write it as "It is well enough for you to write this one e-mail and my reply to it."

Comment: @Thursagen - Thank you for this suggestion, but ... would that not mean that “to write” will be related both to “one e-mail” and to “my reply”? Will it not sound as if the same person (the one whom I am addressing) was writing both e-mail and the reply?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  If you're saying "X **and** Y", then they *are* enough.  If you're just saying "X.  And then Y", it would be *is* enough.

Do the email *and* the reply cover it well enough?  "are"

Or are you just mentioning the email, then saying that the reply covers it well enough?  "is"